# Write filtered NSArray back to plist

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsarray, plist

I load plist to NSArry, filter that array to capture the data I need, and then present the data to a UITableView. That works great.

**EDIT:**

I'm working with the array of dictionaries. Plist is filled with array of dictionaries.

This is what I do:

```
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/data.plist"];
//array is filled with dictionaries
array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

//filter the array to catch appropriate data (there are maybe 10 objects):
self.arrayFiltered = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[array count]];
NSDictionary *dict;
for (dict in array)
    if ([[dict valueForKey:@"globalKey"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:year]])
        [arrayFiltrirani addObject:dict];
```

Now I fill the tableView with the data from the arrayFiltered. Now I want to delete a row from the tableView and arrayFiltered.

```
[self.arrayFiltrirani removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

BUT!!! How do I update original array and save it to the plist?

Comment: What is your actual intention? The code you've provided does exactly what you say it does. It takes an array and turns it into a .plist. Are you wanting to keep the existing file contents as well as the new file contents? That is something that NSDictionary would be better suited for.

Comment: When I save my filtered array to the plist, all previous data gets overriten and now in the plist is only the data from the arrayFiltered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem. Basically I made 2 arrays from the main array, "Filtered" array and "Other" array.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/data.plist"];

array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

self.arrayFiltered = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[array count]];
self.arrayOther = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[array count]];

NSDictionary *dict;
for (dict in array)
    if ([[dict valueForKey:@"globalKey"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:godinaMjesec]])
        [arrayFiltered addObject:dict];
    else {
        [arrayOther addObject:dict];
    }
```

Now when I want to delete data from the arrayFiltered (from which the tableView takes the data):

```
[self.arrayFiltered removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

To write over original array:

```
[self.arrayOther addObjectsFromArray:self.arrayFiltered];
[self.arrayOther writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

This is maybe not a right way to do it, but it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using dictionaries, you'll want to write the actual dictionary container object back to the data.plist file, so

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [masterArray objectAtIndex:indexOfDictionary];
NSMutableArray *myDataArray = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"dataArray"];
[myDataArray removeObject:objRemovedFromTable]; //or removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row
NSString *filePath = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
[masterArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what I have to do? In my array I have the hole .plist with dictionaries. In my arrayFiltered I have the dictionaries that are presented in the tableView (there are just few of them, not the hole .plist!!). So should I save the original array or the arrayFiltered to the .plist (writeToFile:filePath)? If I removeObject from the arrayFiltered and save it, it replaces everything else. How to find the dict that i'm deleting in the original array?

Comment: I didn't see you edited your answer. How do I get indexOfDictionary?

Comment: Only you can answer that. How are you accessing the data that populates the tableview? The point is, you have to write the the container file back to disk, whatever object is storing ALL of the dictionaries that you're playing with.

Comment: What you should do is implement a property for the main array, like @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *mainArray; load it up like this: self.mainArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; then just call [mainArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

Answer (score 0):

If it's a large plist file that takes a while to write then you may be using the wrong tool.  I would use Core Data to enable the deletion of individual rows of data.